# GLSL : why this bloomEffect and gloomEffect code output only black & white image?

Tags: opengl-es, shader, glsles

When i use `TbloomEffect` and `TgloomEffect` (Delphi component) under android/iOS (so with openGL) then it's produce only **black & white** output :( under windows (DX11) then it's work ok. I guess it's a bug in the delphi source code but i can't find what wrong in the original GLSL code below I extracted from the original delphi source:

`TgloomEffect` use :

```
varying vec4 TEX0;
vec4 _ret_0;
vec3 _TMP4;
float _TMP3;
vec3 _x0014;
vec3 _TMP15;
float _grey0022;
float _grey0028;
vec3 _TMP35;
uniform float _GloomIntensity;
uniform float _BaseIntensity;
uniform float _GloomSaturation;
uniform float _BaseSaturation;
uniform sampler2D _Input;
void main()
{
    vec4 _color1;
    vec3 _base;
    vec3 _gloom;
    vec3 _TMP10;
    _color1 = texture2D(_Input, TEX0.xy);
    _base = 1.0 - _color1.xyz/_color1.w;
    _x0014 = (_base - 2.50000000E-001)/7.50000000E-001;
    _TMP4 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _x0014);
    _TMP15 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP4);
    _grey0022 = dot(_TMP15, vec3( 3.00000012E-001, 5.89999974E-001, 1.09999999E-001));
    _TMP3 = _grey0022 + _GloomSaturation*(_TMP15.x - _grey0022);
    _gloom = vec3(_TMP3, _TMP3, _TMP3)*_GloomIntensity;
    _grey0028 = dot(_base, vec3( 3.00000012E-001, 5.89999974E-001, 1.09999999E-001));
    _TMP3 = _grey0028 + _BaseSaturation*(_base.x - _grey0028);
    _base = vec3(_TMP3, _TMP3, _TMP3)*_BaseIntensity;
    _TMP4 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _gloom);
    _TMP35 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP4);
    _base = _base*(1.0 - _TMP35);
    _TMP10 = (1.0 - (_base + _gloom))*_color1.w;
    _ret_0 = vec4(_TMP10.x, _TMP10.y, _TMP10.z, _color1.w);
    gl_FragColor = _ret_0;
    return;
}
```

and `TBloomEffect` use :

```
varying vec4 TEX0;
vec4 _ret_0;
vec3 _TMP5;
float _TMP4;
vec3 _TMP3;
vec3 _TMP14;
vec3 _x0015;
float _grey0021;
float _grey0027;
vec3 _TMP34;
uniform float _BloomIntensity;
uniform float _BaseIntensity;
uniform float _BloomSaturation;
uniform float _BaseSaturation;
uniform sampler2D _Input;
void main()
{
    vec4 _color1;
    vec3 _base;
    vec3 _bloom;
    vec3 _TMP11;
    _color1 = texture2D(_Input, TEX0.xy);
    _base = _color1.xyz/_color1.w;
    _x0015 = (_base - 2.50000000E-001)/7.50000000E-001;
    _TMP3 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _x0015);
    _TMP14 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP3);
    _grey0021 = dot(_TMP14, vec3( 3.00000012E-001, 5.89999974E-001, 1.09999999E-001));
    _TMP4 = _grey0021 + _BloomSaturation*(_TMP14.x - _grey0021);
    _bloom = vec3(_TMP4, _TMP4, _TMP4)*_BloomIntensity;
    _grey0027 = dot(_base, vec3( 3.00000012E-001, 5.89999974E-001, 1.09999999E-001));
    _TMP4 = _grey0027 + _BaseSaturation*(_base.x - _grey0027);
    _base = vec3(_TMP4, _TMP4, _TMP4)*_BaseIntensity;
    _TMP5 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _bloom);
    _TMP34 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP5);
    _base = _base*(1.0 - _TMP34);
    _TMP11 = (_base + _bloom)*_color1.w;
    _ret_0 = vec4(_TMP11.x, _TMP11.y, _TMP11.z, _color1.w);
    gl_FragColor = _ret_0;
    return;
}
```

What wrong in those 2 GLSL codes that make output only in black & white ?

Comment: Please stop posting non-Delphi code using the Delphi tag. Either show the equivalent Delphi code, or tag it correctly

Comment: @DaveNottage: it's extracted directly from delphi source (unit FMX.Filter.Standard), maybe you don't know but Delphi use widely openGL ...

Comment: That does not make what I said any less true. If you're going to tag it as Delphi, post Delphi code

Comment: @DaveNottage : does the delphi component TbloomEffect / TGloomEffect work or not ? so is it a delphi bug or not ? ... so with tag you want I add when i speak about a bug in a delphi component ?

Comment: It's not about whether or not it works. You've tagged the question as Delphi; this is not Delphi code. Also, that code is not in FMX.Filter.Standard as you claim anyway (at least not in Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3).

Comment: @DaveNottage: It is fmx.filter.standard ! it's the code of the TbloomFilter  / TGloomFilter that are located in FMX.Filter.Standard.pas (Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3) ...

Comment: It would have helped in your comments to point out that you've used *something else* to translate *hex codes* into GLSL.

Comment: @DaveNottage : I didn't remember the word "hex" so i didn't know how to say it so i didn't say it

Answer (score 0):

because of a bug in delphi ...

good code is :

```
varying vec4 TEX0;
vec4 _ret_0;
vec3 _TMP4;
vec3 _TMP3;
vec3 _x0014;
vec3 _TMP15;
float _grey0022;
float _grey0028;
vec3 _TMP35;
uniform float _GloomIntensity;
uniform float _BaseIntensity;
uniform float _GloomSaturation;
uniform float _BaseSaturation;
uniform sampler2D _Input;
void main()
{
    vec4 _color1;
    vec3 _base;
    vec3 _gloom;
    vec3 _TMP10;

    _color1 = texture2D(_Input, TEX0.xy);
    _base = 1.0 - _color1.xyz/_color1.w;
    _x0014 = (_base - 0.25)/0.75;
    _TMP4 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _x0014);
    _TMP15 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP4);

    _grey0022 = dot(_TMP15, vec3( 0.3, 0.59, 0.11));
    _TMP3 = vec3(_grey0022, _grey0022, _grey0022) + _GloomSaturation*(_TMP15 - vec3(_grey0022, _grey0022, _grey0022));
    _gloom = _TMP3*_GloomIntensity;

    _grey0028 = dot(_base, vec3( 0.3, 0.59, 0.11));
    _TMP3 = vec3(_grey0028, _grey0028, _grey0028) + _BaseSaturation*(_base - vec3(_grey0028, _grey0028, _grey0028));
    _base = _TMP3*_BaseIntensity;

    _TMP4 = min(vec3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), _gloom);
    _TMP35 = max(vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), _TMP4);

    _base = _base*(1.0 - _TMP35);
    _TMP10 = (1.0 - (_base + _gloom))*_color1.w;
    _ret_0 = vec4(_TMP10.x, _TMP10.y, _TMP10.z, _color1.w);

    gl_FragColor = _ret_0;
    return;
}
```